# Cakephp Auth component deny function has stopped working

Tags: authentication, cakephp-1.3

I have small project, that use cakephp. One day I noticed, that all users can access admin panel. There beforeFilter of AdminController:

```
    function beforeFilter() {
        parent::beforeFilter();

        $this->Auth->deny('*');

        if($this->Auth->user('group_id') == '1'){
            $this->Auth->allow('*');
        }
    }
```

I can leave only `$this->Auth->deny('*');` and it still dont prevent access.
I'm sure, that it works several months ago.

P.S. `$this->Auth->deny('*');` makes list of allowed actions empty, but i still can access. Any suggestions?